# how to output degree symbol in C programs with iso_8859-1?

Tags: c, iso-8859-1

I looked up the manual of iso_8859-1 and found the degree symbol:

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char   Description
260   176   B0     °     DEGREE SIGN
```

Code:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char chr = 176; //stores the extended ASCII of a symbol
    printf("Character with an ascii code of 251: %c \n", chr);
    return 0;
}
```

But it printed out as `?`.

How could I output a degree symbol in a C programme? Do I need to include some files?

Comment: Either your locale isn't set to *iso-8859-1* (nowadays, *utf-8* would be quite common) or your font is just missing the corresponding glyph. But anyways, what's the `251` here?

Comment: The way you try to do this is correct, you need to configure your terminal to use ISO-8859-1 though.

Comment: If you are working on Windows surely is not iso8859-1, the console uses some kind of "OEM corepage". You should use WideCharToMultibyte to convert from a wchar_t.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Please rather use `wctomb()` which is the standard function for this purpose.

Comment: @FUZxxl: getting the code page right in console on Windows is a platform-specific nightmare anyway, better use a decently documented function instead of the atrocious, badly documented C locale stuff.

Comment: Don't use iso-8859-1. Use [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) in 2015!

Comment: btw, works for me even on `de_DE.UTF-8` locale, output is `Character with an ascii code of 251: °` (still why 251??)

Comment: @MatteoItalia How is `wctomb()` poorly documented or atrocious? If you like your programs to work on Windows only, I can understand that, but please don't spread FUD to other people.

Comment: @FUZxxl AFAIR there's no standard requirement about what range of characters `wchar_t` **must** support. If I'm wrong, I'd appreciate some hint ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen There isn't so a platform without multibyte support can shim it out with `typedef char wchar_t`. It's 16 bit on Windows as far as I'm concerned and 32 bit on UNIX.

Comment: @MatteoItalia FUZxxl is right. Research a little, and you'll find that Japan especially opposes the current state of the unification of characters. Wikipedia expresses some issues, such as [unifying language-dependent glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_unification#Examples_of_language-dependent_glyphs). [Variant forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_form_%28Unicode%29) are being added to fix this issue, but I doubt adoption will be swift. I'm curious if they will affect the GB 18030 "mega code-page" as well... Anyway, sorry to say, but legacy character sets are still a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use other characters than ASCII, on most platforms you have to switch to a "locale" that is able to handle such characters. At the beginning of your `main` you should have

```
   #include <locale.h>
   int main(void) {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   ...
   }
```

here the empty string `""` literally stands for the default locale of your platform.

Now, what locale is supported by your platform is something that you'd have to find out yourself, you didn't give us enough information. I'd strongly suggest not to go with an obsolete one as you were proposing but to go for UTF-8.

Usually you may embed UTF-8 character sequences naturally in normal C strings, so something like `"105° C"` should print out as the degree character.

Comment: Although correct, I think this answer is opening a can of worms with dragons lurking and all stuff ... are we already "there" so *utf-8* encoding in C source code is considered a "safe choice"? Even then, how about `strlen()` and stuff? Using `wchar_t` for anything that's not in *us-ascii* would be the really safe way, but you'd have to explain a lot more for this :) (note not my downvote, but it's probably for similar doubts)

Comment: Downvoted, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` is a recipe for disaster, almost no library can live with anything but the C locale (especially regarding LC_NUMERIC). LC_CTYPE maybe, but you still have to be careful because you are modifying the global state of the program in a system-specific way - are you sure all your program is ready to run fine with standard library functions (innocent-looking stuff like scanf or strtod) subtly modified in a system and platform dependent way?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: wchar_t is a red herring, it's specified so vaguely that it's not portable anyway (on Windows it's UTF-16, so you still have the same worries of a variable length encoding) and is badly supported everywhere (on Unix is mostly ignored, and try to use wcout on Windows with any vaguely exotic character).

Comment: @MatteoItalia indeed, I remember having been there a long time ago and back then using my own storage format with 4 bytes for one character, together with `iconv()`. Yep, dragons .... (btw, what would you say is best practice for supporting the whole range of Unicode? I guess just use some existing library?)

Comment: @MatteoItalia and maybe I remeber incorrectly, but I think it's even worse and `wchar_t` on windows was just *UCS-2*?

Comment: IIRC it was UCS2 up to NT4, Windows 2000 introduced UTF16, 9x was always a local encoding thing. As for the support in the various versions of the CRT, God only knows.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, wow, somebody downvoting a correct answer without providing anything usable of its own. I thought SO was a nice place. And this recipe works on all modern Linux systems, and also MacOs (I guess). It is simply what the C standard provides.

Comment: @JensGusted: the C standard provides a lot of broken or outdated stuff, such as locales. If you are working on *nix, just forget all this shit, leave the default C locale and write UTF-8 (you wouldn't test it anyway with different locales). On Windows you can use the "wide" functions (require some tweaking to work correctly with "exotic" characters), or you can set the thread CP to UTF-8 and work as on Linux (kinda works, but not supported and requires some magic calls). There's no portable way to write unicode in console, and setlocale has always been a source of problems, not of solutions.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, all I can deduce from what your are saying is that  all platforms but Windows work.  So the first problem is there, and not in the C standard. If your compiler/platform isn't capable of UTF-8, it is time to switch.

Comment: @JensGustedt: what I'm saying is that the only platform where you do need CP conversion is the one where locales work worst; but they are a wrong solution anyway, since it's affecting the global state of a program for a local problem (output on a single stream). But do as you wish, as long as you are on a "simple", mostly NOP locale it will work. Call me when you'll have your program that cannot read back what it wrote, or the need to write a single stream in a specific encoding, or the need to use strtod or sscanf on machine-generated data,

Comment: @JensGustedt: or when you'll have to debug strange crashes due to libraries which try to change the locale to a sane default and change it back after doing their own thing (hint: locale is global in the process). This is all stuff that happened to me, and comes both from bad implementations and bad design in first place (the original sin is to suppose that there's *one* current encoding in the whole program, and to make all formatting functions locale-aware, while in 99% of situations you use them to deal with machine generated data).

Comment: That's why I came to the conclusion that it's better to leave this stuff to better libraries (localization is relevant mostly in UI, where we have libraries which actually grok the real problems) and neuter completely the standard library stuff, so that it does the least surprising thing (default decimal separators, plain bytes output without conversions).

Answer (score 3):

the ASCII code for the degree celsius is 248. You can declare this as a char in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char ch=248;
printf("Today's temperature was 23%cC",ch);
}
```

Comment: ASCII per se is 7 bits and only covers character codes up to 127. Maybe there is some encoding scheme where character 248 is the degree symbol, but it's certainly not ASCII, you haven't said which one it is, and it's not clear if it's the one that OP wants.