# ISO 8859 Encoding in c#

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I want to know encoding name which supports all the ISO-8859 (like ISO-8859-1,ISO-8859-2,etc.).  Can you please help me out of this.?

I have used,

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(xmlText)))
```

but it does not support degree symbol.

Thanks,
Ganesh. K

Comment: ISO8859-1 definitely contains the degree symbol

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398621/system-text-encoding-getencodingiso-8859-1-throws-platformnotsupportedexcept

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859 - character value 176

Comment: What is the contents of _"xmlText"_ - maybe the degree symbol is not encoded in that string as you expect. Does the XML file specify an encoding?

Comment: ISO8859-1 replaces degree symbol with question-mark (?)

Comment: Your end result is a memory stream. "question mark" indicates you're already visualising that as text again, meaning the error might just be in your visualising. How does the ° symbol look as _byte_, though? I get "° = 176 (0xB0)"

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, ISO-8859-1 **does** include the degree symbol.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188044/how-to-output-degree-symbol-in-c-programs-with-iso-8859-1) for help on how to debug.

Comment: The above code replaces degree symbol with question-mark (?) while encoding

Comment: Try: - `using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252 /*Western Europe*/).GetBytes(xmlText)))`

Comment: Also. ISO-8859-1 **is** the correct encoding, the issue must be elsewhere. Either in your code or in the xml file.

Comment: @ganku007 You _can't_ get a question mark when encoding; you're encoding to _bytes_, and "question mark" is not a byte value, it's a character. You're getting that when _decoding_ the encoded bytes, and _that's_ probably where something is wrong. If this is simply when viewing the xml, then most likely, the xml header does not actually identify the contents as being iso-8859-1.